# Glitches after locking and unlocking screen

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, gpu

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and every time I lock my screen and then I login I have this problem.

[image: Screen Glitches]

I'm using nvidia drivers and when I switch to the integrated GPU (intel) the problem is fixed. I have also a problem when youtube videos goes fullscreen, the screen freeze. I think this is a problem with nvidia drivers (version 390.77). This is my configuration

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b4000000-b407ffff
```